# why asyncpostback in asp.net webform page is so heavy

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

i have a webform asp.net page with near 40 controls and 50 server validator on it
and i`m using updatepanel with asyncpostback trigger on it like below :

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdblHeiatElmi" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtCodeMeli" EventName="TextChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chbkDaneshkade" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpProvince1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drpProvince2" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
```

my question is : why my async postback data is so heavy ?
i`ve check data sent back to server and it's near 1200KB, in every asyncpostback .

Comment: I suppose that's because of the `ViewState` which is sent on each AJAX request.

Comment: i suspected to that to ,how do i check the exact sizeof viewstat ?

Comment: You can look at the payload sent during the AJAX request. The ViewState is sent as a hidden input field.

Answer (score 3):

`UpdatePanel` was an easy but heavy approach to AJAX when most ASP.NET developers weren't prepared for AJAX at all.

Instead of exchaging JSON/XML data with the server-side, it sends affected by some action HTML within the `ContentTemplate` placeholder. It also exhanges the `ViewState`.

Since we're in 2016 I would say that you should start to think about learning plain AJAX or using some third-party framework like jQuery (at least) to perform AJAX calls which work with data to leverage a good separation of concerns to optimize your client-server communications.

Its [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) states:

> ASP.NET UpdatePanel controls enable you to build rich, client-centric
>   Web applications. By using UpdatePanel controls, you can refresh
>   selected parts of the page instead of refreshing the whole page with a
>   postback. This is referred to as performing a partial-page update. An
>   ASP.NET Web page that contains a ScriptManager control and one or more
>   UpdatePanel controls can automatically participate in partial-page
>   updates, without custom client script

.

Comment: `Since we're in 2015` - still :-)?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Omg, you'll downvote my answer for this, won't you? :(((((( I'm going to fix this;P

Comment: Of course, it is incorrect :-D +1 by the way for a good answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  NoOOOOOoooOOoo (voice from the crypt)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Thank you. We still need to repair the damage that ASP.NET AJAX did more than 10 years ago... The AJAX for the lazy :(

Comment: I would rather say we still need to repair the damage that ASP.NET did more than 13 years ago.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Yes, you're right. In my opinion, in 10 years we'll we also talking about we need to repeair the damage that Angular and that "my own way" of developing web produced to the web development community....

Comment: @DarinDimitrov And it doesn't mean that I'm not using Angular but it's the same mistake as WebForms: the Angular way....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your try to answer my question .
But my secondary problem is that i need to learn pure ajax ,
my first problem was why my asyncpostbacks are so heavy and the was i putt all my page including partial fields into one update panel , and the answer is i need to separate each partial update in multiple updatepanel.